# Arch Linux startx error

Tags: arch-linux

[image: Arch startx shows error(1)]

Setup Arch Linux on VirtualBox but unable to startx. Also i cant reboot without using sudo as it says failed to talk to init daemon.
Using cat on the log file shows this:
[image: Cat on log file]

Comment: The X server failed to start. Look into the mentioned log file (`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`) to find out why.

Comment: I did less /var/log/Xorg.0.log but it just shows ~ symbols all over the file and nothing else.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox and ArchLinux are you using?

Comment: Both are the latest versions respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Before using `Xorg` on archlinux, [it need to be configured](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Configuration). One way to do it is to run:

```
Xorg :0 -configure
cp ~/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Comment: Server terminated with error 2. To test the server run  X -config /root/xorg.conf.new.

Comment: And when using cp it cannot find home/username/xorg.conf.new

Comment: Please append the X server error log file contents to your question. (/var/log/Xorg.0.log)

Comment: The second image is the log file which says screen init failed for driver.

Comment: Gave up on the installation. Deleted the arch iso

Comment: Maybe someday later shall give it another try.

Comment: Well, that's too late for you but I reproduced the issue (at least the same Xorg error logs) and that was fixed after I rebooted the VM.

Comment: I had sudo rebooted it numerous times with no success.

Comment: Archlinux looks to be gratuitously cumbersome anyway. Installation documentation looks like a "treasure hunt game"...

Comment: Well I will give it another shot soon

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be related to https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14732. In such a case you would need to use the newest VirtualBox (5.0.18), and also install guest additions before starting X.

Comment: I have the 5.0.18 installed

Comment: Did you install VirtualBox Guest Additions in the ArchLinux?

Comment: The virtualbox guest utils are up to date.